# Prove: if the complementary graph is connected, then graph isn't necessarily unconnected.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have such a question. There is a theorem related to graphs that says, that if a graph is disconnected then it's complementary graph is connected. But how can I prove that the inverse is not true, i.e. if the complementary of a graph is connected then the graph isn't necessarily unconnected ? Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to prove the first statement? That is, a disconnected graph $G$ has a connected complement $\bar G$?

Comment: @Joffan Yes, by giving an example. This question is a part of an exercise. The first part is what you asked, the second is what I posted.

Comment: Hmm, no, that's a demonstration of feasibility not a proof of inevitability. By contrast, providing a counterexample to an assertion does disprove. There is a fundamental asymmetry between proof and disproof. Anyhow as you say that wasn't what you were asking, so no worries.

Answer (score 3):

In other words you are asking if a graph and its complement can both be connected? Sure they can. For example, take any self-complementary graph: the $4$-point path $P_4$, the cycle $C_5$, etc.